# Overriding in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I have a generic method in abstract parent class which I want to override in the concrete child:

**Parent class:**

```
public abstract class AbstractParentDataAccess<S extends AbstractParentDataModel> 
{
   ...
  public void save(Collection<? extends S> collection) {...}
   ...
}
```

**Child Class:**

```
public class ConcreteDataAccess extends AbstractParentDataAccess<ConcreteDataModel> 
{
   ...
   // this does not compile
   @Override
   public void save(Collection<ConcreteDataModel> collection) {...}

   // this compiles but never gets called, the parent method is being called instead
   @Override
   public void save(Collection<? extends ConcreteDataModel> collection) {...}
   ...

}
```

ConcreteDataModel class inherits from AbstractParentDataModel:

```
public class ConcreteDataModel extends AbstractParentDataModel {...}
```

Here is how I call the save method:

```
...
@Autowired
private ConcreteDataAccess concreteDataAccess;
....
List<ConcreteDataModel> dataList = DataService.getDataList();
concreteDataAccess.save(dataList);
...
```

So my question is:

Why:

1. does the first method not compile?
2. is parent method being called instead of child method in the second one and how to fix it?

Comment: Please show how you are creating the instances and calling the method.

Comment: How did you check which method is being called?

Comment: 1. It doesn't compile because it's not override-equivalent to a method in a superclass.

Comment: @AndyTurner I just pass a List of the ConcreteDataModel and Call the Method

Comment: @codeflush.dev I debugged it and parent method is called

Comment: @BakriBitar please show the code: a [mcve]. You are doing something that leads to a result you don't expect, and we can't say what that is if you don't show us.

Comment: Show us some actual code, how you call it and how the method is implemented

Comment: 1. You have `S = ConcreteDataModel`, and you're accepting a `List<? extends S>` in the method.  `List<ConcreteDataModel>` != `List<? extends ConcreteDataModel>`, hence it doesn't compile.
2. The parent method can't be being called unless you're calling `super.save` in your method.  In which case, _yes_, but only indirectly via the subclass' method.

Comment: The first declaration should be actually ```public void save(Collection<S> collection){...} ``` since you already captured S on the class type

Comment: @user2478398 another option of how the superclass method is called is that it's not being called through this subclass at all, but rather on another subclass which doesn't override this method.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos: They're not equivalent.  `Collection<S>` would allow you to `add` any instance of `S` to it.  `Collection<? extends S>` wouldn't as it wouldn't be able to identify whether your `S` instance was an _appropriate_ extension of `S`.

Comment: @AndyTurner: That's true, but I'd hope that would stand out like a sore thumb. :/

Comment: @user2478398 ...and this is why we need to see that code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *impossible* given what you have given us that the parent method is being called. You've typoed the methodname (`save`), or your calling code has an issue here.

Note that at the VM level, generics do not exist; both methods have the exact same JVM signature: `save(Ljava/util/Collection;)V` - even if the generics are wildly out of whack, it's the same method as far as the VM is concerned, and thus, the `save` in your child class overrides the one from parent.

`List<ConcreteDataModel>` does not compile here, because a `Collection<? extends S>` allows more types than `List<ConcreteDataModel>` does. For example, this:

```
List<ConcreteDataModel> x = new ArrayList<SubTypeOfConcreteDataModel>();
```

does not compile, but this:

```
List<? extends ConcreteDataModel> x = new ArrayList<SubTypeOfConcreteDataModel>();
```

does. (Reason: You can call `x.add(new ConcreteDataModel());` on a `List<ConcreteDataModel>`, putting something in your list of SubTypeOfConcreteDataModel that isn't a SubTypeOfConcreteDataModel. Note that you can't call `.add()` on a `List<? extends WhateverYouWantToWriteHere>` at all, unless you pass literally `null`.